# Reload div with jquery --> php file included --> copy causes failed to open stream

Tags: php, jquery, html, copy, reload

I got a problem with `copy(file,to_file)`, I think.

On my ***initial HTML file*** the following code is included:

```
<div id="abocaptcha">
  <?php include("system/library/abocaptcha/aboCaptcha.php"); ?>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Within ***aboCaptcha.php*** the following code:

```
$from = $imgPath.'q_'.$icons[$randomize].'.'.$imgExt;
$to  = $imgPath.'abocaptcha.'.$imgExt;
if (!copy($from, $to)) {echo "copy error...\n";}
```

So, when the HTML file is initially loaded, everything is working fine, `aboCaptcha.php` is working perfect, the copy command is doing his job.
But when I want to refresh the div `#abocaptcha` later on via:

```
$("#abocaptcha").load('system/library/abocaptcha/aboCaptcha.php');
```

the copy command causes the following error:

> Warning: copy(catalog/view/theme/kitro/image/abocaptcha/q_icon02.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /.../system/library/abocaptcha/aboCaptcha.php on line 13
>   copy error...

Line 13 is exactly the copy command...

I experimented with file permissions already, no effect.
Can you help me?

Thanks

Andreas

Comment: I suspect the /.../system/library/abocaptcha/aboCaptcha.php somehow changed the root directory of your php file, so it could not find the file. verify that first.

Comment: Thanks Twocode. I verify that. There is the copy-command and afterwards some images are loaded from the exact same path. The images are loaded correctly, so I think the path is correctly...

Comment: Ok, based on the API doc: http://api.jquery.com/load/ seems the load() function post stuff to the php file, I would assume your PHP file is waiting for a $_POST with some params from client side. test your code by changing $from and $to with fixed path see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Twocode, you pointed me to the right direction. In fact on first call and jquery call the root is different! 
I solved my problem with php `if file_exists()`and doing for jquery call another path. THANK YOU VERY MUCH :-)

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for this kind of problems here : stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory